# click function is a property of an object in emit event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events

I came across the following code and it obviously emit `notification-alert` event and an object as a parameter

```js
       this.$root.$emit('notification-alert', {
          text,
          type: 'warning',
          click: () => this.unselect(file),
        });
```

What I don't understand is this line `click: () => this.unselect(file)`

- How can a click function be considered as a property of that object?
- What does that mean and how can that function be used afterwards?

Comment: It's not a "click function", it's a function named "click"

Comment: @yoduh you mean it is not about the default javascript **onclick Event** ? but a custom function that was called `click` ?

Comment: yes, exactly right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`click` is a callback that is passed as a property of event object to the place where this event is listened, where it can be called:

```
   this.$root.$on('notification-alert', e => {
     // calls this.unselect(file) in the context where click function was defined
     e.click();
   });
```

Comment: theoretically I got what you mean, yet can you append a small example that is runnable to watch how it works ?

Comment: This is the actual example. Put this in mounted() in any component that is currently in use, this will make this.unselect(file) to be called when this.$root.$emit(...) is called